# Can Powerpoint update two Excel objects that are from the same Excel file?

Tags: macos, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-excel-2011

I've been reading through the forums and haven't come across a definite answer for my query. I have a PPT presentation that includes 2 different worksheets from the same Excel file, pasted as Excel worksheet objects. If I make a change in the Excel file it affects both worksheets while in Excel, but because they are pasted as separate objects in PPT, I have to make the same changes twice by clicking through to Excel from Powerpoint. Is there any way for both objects to update automatically when I change the Excel file?

The caveat is these PPT files are often emailed back and forth, and I want to avoid having to also email the Excel file and use a relative/absolute path solution. Having the Excel file embedded is fine, but because both objects are pasted from the same file, I'm hoping there is some way to make updates only once.

I'm working with PowerPoint and Excel 2011 for Mac. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.  Once you embed an excel object into a power point, it is a copy of the original dataset you copied it from, not a linked dataset.  There may be a way using vba in powerpoint to update the cells but to your question that was asked, they are not linked and can't be.